# How can I use an 'align*' environment inside a 'tabular' environment?

Tags: tables, align

I'm trying to do something similar to what's inside the table (the part where `*` is defined) in the following picture

[image: Usage of a align* inside a tabular environment. 1]

My attempt is

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|m{12cm}|}
\hline    
Dada $A$ un conjunto no vacío. Una ley de composición interna en $A$ (l.c.i) es una función\\
\begin{align*}
 * \colon A\times A &\to A)\\
 (x,y) &\mapsto x*y.\\
\end{align*}\\
\hline  
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

But it fails to work. How could I write what's inside the table?  (Any method is ok, I don't need it to be `align*`.)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Don't use `align*`; instead, use `aligned`.

Comment: To elaborate on what @Mico said, use `$\begin{aligned}...\end{aligned}$`.

Comment: Thanks, it's better now. The only problem is that it's not centered (I only changed what you mentioned (and placed  de aligned environment inside of "$")) it looks similar to whats on the picture expect the parte where * is defined is on the left hand side. Any tips to solving this?

Comment: @RandomUser - Please see the answer I posted a minute ago.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,amsmath}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|m{12cm}|}
\hline    
Dada $A$ un conjunto no vacío. Una ley de composición interna 
en $A$ (l.c.i) es una función\\
\hfil
$\begin{aligned}
 * \colon A\times A &\to     A \\
   (x,y)            &\mapsto x*y
\end{aligned}$
\hfil\\
\hline  
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. How did you make it so that the definition of "*" is centered? I can't tell.

Comment: @RandomUser - I surrounded the `aligned` environment with `\hfil` instructions.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that you'll run into a never-ending series of issues with other definitions. What if you need a second paragraph? Do you really want to put `\displaystyle` into every faked display math? etc.

Comment: @DonaldHosek - I have absolutely no idea what you're trying to get at with your comments. Maybe start by clarifying what "Do you really want to put `\displaystyle` into every faked display math" is supposed to mean? AFAICT, there is not a single `\displaystyle` directive anywhere in my answer...

Comment: @Mico Try doing a `\sum` in your math and see how it comes out. It's possible to do lots of manual fudging to make something look "right" but it's usually better to do things right. In this case, the problem is that you're using inline math to fake display math. The solutions below allow the definition to be typed using proper display math instead of centering an inline math.

Comment: @DonaldHosek - The contents of an `aligned` environment are in display-math mode *automatically*. I still have no idea what you're alleging regarding "proper display math instead of centering an inline math".

Comment: It's the difference between `\\\hfil$...$\hfil\\` and `\[...\]` Your solution solves this definition but doesn't cover the general case. Not to mention the whole munging up structure and presentation. You have a solution that covers *this particular case* but will run into issues with others.

Comment: @DonaldHosek - Trying to pull the old trick of changing the subject when you've lost badly on the merits of the argument? I'm still not impressed.

Comment: @Mico I've not changed the subject at all. I've tried rephrasing what I've said in multiple ways. I've not changed the subject at all. I do see that my last post lost a backtick and the code snippet should have read `\\\hfil$...$\hfil\\`` and `\[...\]` so perhaps that's your confusion?

Comment: @DonaldHosek - Let's see: You started by asking, "Do you really want to put `\displaystyle` into every faked display math?" In the next comment, you tried the taunt, "Try doing a `\sum` in your math and see how it comes out", followed by the damning accusation "the problem is that you're using inline math to fake display math." None of this has any substance -- and you know it. So now it's on to something far more grandiose, about my answer not solving "the general case" -- ever so conveniently glossing over what this general case might be about. Guess what? I'm still not impressed.

Comment: I started with "The problem with this approach is that you'll run into a never-ending series of issues with other definitions. What if you need a second paragraph? Do you really want to put` \displaystyle` into every faked display math? etc." I've been talking about how the solution doesn't generalize from the first sentence.

Comment: @DonaldHosek - The gist of your claims appears to be that encasing the `aligned` environment in `\hfil$ ... $\hfil` is inferior to encasing it in `\[ ... \]`, possibly because the latter method covers "the general case" -- whatever that may be. Guess what? The latter method inserts significant amounts of vertical whitespace above and below the `aligned` environment. This *simply cannot be correct* for the OP's use case. I suppose one could fix this blunder by encasing the entire `\[ ... \]` construct in a `minipage` of width `\hsize`. Is that what you imagine the "general case" to be??

Comment: Compare your output to the original poster's desired output, There *should* be more whitespace. It's not just the `\[...\]` that should be enclosed in a `minipage` but the whole definition. And once you have a `minipage` you can just enclose that in a `\fbox` to avoid creating a `tabular` environment. egreg's solution is effectively that but uses `tcolorbox` to cleanly encapsulate everything. Then the contents of the definition can be typeset without having to do any manual formatting, they act just like any other chunk of LaTeX and can have paragraphs or the original `align*`.

Comment: @DonaldHosek - You're a whiner and a sore loser, that's all. I have nothing further to say to you.

Answer (score 7):

I believe you don't want to use `tabular` for that.

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,array}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definición}[section]

\tcolorboxenvironment{definition}{
  enhanced jigsaw,
  colframe=black,
  interior hidden,
  before skip=\topsep,
  after skip=\topsep,
  arc=0pt,
  boxrule=0.4pt,
}

\begin{document}

\section{Definiciones generales}

Nuestra primera definición captura la noción operador entre elemente de un conjunto.

\begin{definition}[Ley de composición interna]
Dada $A$ un conjunto no vacío. Una ley de composición interna en $A$ (l.c.i,) 
es una función
\[
\begin{array}{@{} r @{} c >{{}}c<{{}} @{} c @{}}
 * \colon & A\times A & \to     & A \\
          & (x,y)     & \mapsto & x*y. \\
\end{array}
\]
\end{definition}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I would be inclined to do something like

```
\newenvironment{definition}{\fbox\bgroup\begin{minipage}{12cm}}{\end{minipage}\egroup}

...

\begin{definition}
Dada $A$ un conjunto no vacío. Una ley de composición interna en $A$ (l.c.i) es una función
\begin{align*}
 * \colon A\times A &\to A)\\
 (x,y) &\mapsto x*y.
\end{align*}
\end{definition}
```

rather than use a tabular environment. No idea if this actually works. I don't have a LaTeX installation handy at the moment.